# C# Elegant way to handle checking for an item in a collection

Tags: c#

I've posted a code sample below. Firstly let me explain

termStore.Groups in the code below is a collection of Group Objects (The exact class is irrelevant).

Checking for null : if (termStore.Groups[groupName] == null) seems like a logical (clean) approach, but if the Groups collection is empty then an exception is produced.

using the termStore.Groups.Contains is not an option either because this expects a strong type i.e: .Contains(Group)... not .Contains(GroupName as string)

Can someone recommend a clean / generic way I can check for if an item exists in collection .

Thank you....

```
TermStore termStore = session.TermStores.Where(ts => ts.Name == termStoreName).FirstOrDefault();
                if (termStore.Groups[groupName] == null)
                {
                    termStore.CreateGroup(groupName);
                    termStore.CommitAll();
                }
```

Update: The exact class Sharepoint Taxonomy Classes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.group.aspx

Update 2, the exact collection : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.groupcollection.aspx

Comment: What type is `Groups`? (And yes, it *is* relevant).

Comment: @pst, check update, would a link to TermStore be useful too?

Comment: The Group type itself is probably irrelevant, but certainly the type of termStore.Groups matters a lot!

Comment: For the record, termStore.Groups is of type Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.GroupCollection, and *does* implement IEnumerable<Group>.

Comment: @Lain - thanks for the clarification. I'm just learning LINQ, but its awesome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.GroupCollection implements `IEnumerable<Group>`, so a bit of LINQ is probably just what the doctor ordered:-

```
if(termStore.Groups.Any(x => x.Name == "MyGroup"))
{
   // group contains at least one item matching the predicate.
}
else
{
   // group contains no items matching the predicate.
}
```

You'll need to be using .NET 3.5 or better and add "using System.Linq;" to the top of your file.

**Edit**

If you don't have LINQ available, or if it offends you, or if you've genuinely profiled and found that iterating over Groups is killing performance compared to the string indexer, you could use GroupCollection.Count to avoid the error state:-

```
if (termStore.Groups.Count == 0 || termStore.Groups[groupName] == null)
{
  // Group doesn't exist.
}
```

Comment: Checking out the LINQ option. Thanks.

Comment: The is elegant.  Only problem I see is if Groups contains LOTS of items then you lose the speed of a dictionary lookup if you fall back on IEnumerable (again assuming this collection is underlying a Dictionary of some sort).

Answer (score 2):

[IEnumerable.Any(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx) should work for your case:

```
termsStore.Groups.Any()
```

Comment: @Tim Barrass: some collections (like List), does not required any lambda, just Any(). But of cause you can customize it (if it is L2SQL, for instance), like Any(x => x.Field == "value")

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
termStore.Groups.ContainsKey(groupName)
```

Checks that the key exists, doesn't throw an exception if it doesn't.  This is assuming that Groups is a collection that implements IDictionary.

Comment: Testing it now. Unfortunately it seems Group (being a sharepoint object) doesn't derive from a base type that supports ContainsKey. But thanks :)

Comment: What class is Group then?  The exact class is relevant if you want a method on that class.

Answer (score 0):

May be this

```
termStore.Any() && termStore.Groups.Any() && termStore.Groups[groupName] == null
```

Comment: Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TermStore doesn't itself implement IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: @Iain Galloway, i was not aware of that. I though it was some plain object.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, 2nd attempt.  If Groups doesn't contain the required ContainsKey method then you can write it yourself.  Then you can just use ContainsKey in place of Contains.

```
static class GroupExtensions
{
   public static bool ContainsKey(this Groups groups, string key) 
   {
      try
      {
         if(groups[key] == null)
         {
            return false;
         }
      }
      catch
      {
         return false;
      }
      return true;
   }

}
```

Comment: The problem is that groups[key] throws an exception if the collection is empty.

Comment: Indeed, the above code catches the exception and returns false.

Comment: I prefer to check for an error state rather than try/catch. We can do this even without LINQ (e.g. GroupCollection.Count)